# Baseline Scan ZAP (OWASP) on a defined list of urls

Tags: security, owasp, zap

Is it possible to define a list of URLs that the ZAP baseline (https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/) scan should scan? The default behaviour is that it runs for one minute. I only want 20 defined URLs to be scanned.

It the moment I use the docker container with the following parameters:

```
docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It will run for *up_to* one minute (by default). If your app has only 20 urls then it will hopefully find them much faster than that. If it takes 2 seconds to find them then thats how long it will take to find them. The passive scanning will take a bit longer, but hopefully not too long.

Comment: Right, but if the website has thousands of URLs, the chances are high that the 20 I really want to scan are not included.

Comment: Right now the baseline scan doesnt support importing URLs directly. But it does support scan hooks which allow you to do anything you want: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/ FYI the new Automation Framework will support importing URLs directly, but thats still at an early stage https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/